# Regular Expression | file path .json removal

Tags: excel, string, find-replace

We want to remove .json file from path's name.

input:

CGS\2.6codebase\ingestion\postingestion\fdgr.json

Output should be like below:

CGS\2.6codebase\ingestion\postingestion

Can anyone help with this? using excel under find/replace section? or regular expression?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below formula

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",100)),100)))-1)
```

[image]